# Logic and Sets; questionable deduction skills of the Investigator (Textual problem)

Tags: analysis, logic

The Investigator knows about the 4 suspects P, Q, R and S:

Here we have 4 laws to follow (a,b,c,d)

1. (a) P is guilty if and only if Q is innocent.
2. (b) R is innocent if and only if S is guilty.
3. (c) If S is a perpetrator, then P and vice versa.
4. (d) If S is guilty, then Q is involved.

I made a truth table for all possible outcomes for p q r and s

```
P Q R S 

T T T T
T T T F 
T T F T 
T F T T 
F T T T
T T F F
T F F T 
F F T T 
T F F F 
F F F T 
F F F F
```

then i set the laws in order;

- **Law A:**"P is guilty if and only if Q is innocent." which implies the following; P<=>(¬Q) which is bijuction but I reversed Q with
  negation
- **Law B:** "R is innnocent only if S is guilty" which i also read as bijunction (¬R)<=>S
- **Law C** " If S is a perpetrator, then P and vice versa." which is bijunction but without the need to negate anything, therefore it assume it can be written as S<=>P
- **Law D** "If S is guilty, then Q is involved" where there is no "vice versa" so its vectorish?, like subjunction; S -> Q

So I inserted the negations of R and Q in my table sinceI'll be needing them and added the results of the rules

```
P Q R S ¬R ¬Q P<=>(¬Q) (¬R)<=>S S<=>P S->Q

T T T T  F  F    F          F     T     T
T T T F  F  F    F          T     F     T
T T F T  T  F    F          T     T     T
T F T T  F  T    T          F     T     F
F T T T  F  F    T          F     F     T
T T F F  T  F    F          F     F     T
T F F T  T  T    T          T     T     F
F F T T  F  T    F          T     F     F
T F F F  T  T    T          F     F     T
F F F T  T  T    F          T     F     F
F F F F  T  T    F          F     T     T
```

After this i really got lost, I've been trying a lot of methods but none of them have concrete sense.

I tried getting rid of one suspect by merging two into one following the sense of the laws like S -> (P <=>(¬Q) or something like that, but nothing really makes sense.

The question remains: ***Who did it?***

Comment: Your table has only 11 rows. It should have 16.  You're missing 5 rows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that S<=>P<=>(¬Q) and S=>Q, therefore S is false and consequently P is false as well and R and Q are true. The combination F T T F is not listed. You should have $2^4$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it and after that and just kinda forgot about it, thanks!

It all added up, Q and R were the Killers. There is no great skill behind it, you just have to find the one row where every condition is True(T)

Untill next time!